# graphql Validation error of type FieldsConflict coming when alias is not used

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, github-graphql, graphql-spring-boot

I am getting the error "Validation error of type FieldsConflict" when i am not using aliases in my request. kindly confirm if this is expected or if there is a workaround

```
{
    person(search: [{firstname: "DAN", lastname: "WATLER", country: "FRANCE"}])
    { 
        firstname
        lastname
        country
        age
        address      
    }

    person(search: [{firstname: "FRANK", lastname: "TEE", country: "FRANCE"}])
    { 
        firstname
        lastname
        country
        age
        address      
    }
}
```

Above code gives validation error but if I use aliases shown below, error doesn't come and I get successful response.

I dont want to use aliases, please suggest if any workaround. 
Thanks !

```
{
    dan: person(search: [{firstname: "DAN", lastname: "WATLER", country: "FRANCE"}])
    { 
        firstname
        lastname
        country
        age
        address      
    }

    frank: person(search: [{firstname: "FRANK", lastname: "TEE", country: "FRANCE"}])
    { 
        firstname
        lastname
        country
        age
        address      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually `GraphQL` returns data as JSON objects, and it is not possible to have 2 (valid) objects in a JSON document with the same key (in your case `person`). Hence, it is pretty impossible to achieve what you are describing.

The result of your first query would be something like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "person": {
      "firstname": "DAN",
      ...
    },
    "person": { // this is not valid
      "firstname": "FRANK"
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

And that is why you have to use `alias`.

Another option would be to see if the GraphQL server has a query that returns a list of `person` and the result would be inside of an array, like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "firstname": "DAN",
      ...
    },
    {
      "firstname": "FRANK",
      ...
    }
  [
}
```